# How to read the PAT table of mpegts

Tags: c#, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts

I have just started looking at some work related with reading a mpeg-ts file. This is my first project with video streaming and my first task is to read the program names from the file.

I am currently looking at FFMpeg and FFProbe and have experience in C# and wanted to know which tool/language I should use to do this?

Or do I need another tool or language?

I have launched TSReader and I can see the PAT section which contains the information.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with NetBeans Java IDE and the ProjectX source code.  since ProjectX is designed to transform different formats, it tends to have a lot of descriptive info about the file available on the UI and relatively easy to figure out variable naming in the code as well.

Contrast with other programs, which may be more mysterious in their decoding of the format, because they don't ever display the raw header info and don't have those variables named so clearly in code.